# I get "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)" while trying to run the Flutter application

Tags: flutter, authentication, sharedpreferences, nullable, flutter-getx

I am using the following code inside the `onInit()` method of my `GetXController` auth controller:

```
  Future<bool> autoLogin() async {
    final SharedPreferences? prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs == null ||   !prefs.containsKey('userData') ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      _isAuth.value = true;
    }
    final Map<String, Object> extractedUserData = Map<String, Object>.from(
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData') as String));
    final expiryDate =
        DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate'] as String);

    if (expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return false;
    }
    _token = extractedUserData['token'] as String;
    _userId = extractedUserData['userId'] as String;
    _expiryDate = expiryDate;
    _autoLogout();
    return true;
  }
```

What I am trying to do is to check and see if there is any preferences stored in the storage from previous login and use it to log the user in if it is still valid. But I get the following error message when I try to run the application:

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

And the error comes from the following line of code:

```
final SharedPreferences? prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing null checker and comparison of `prefs == null`